# How to check if facebook popup appears on tapping on a button in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am writing a  stepdefinition for Cucumber Scenario ,in the When clause I click on a button that brings a popup window for facebook share.

Will the driver automatically be focused on the popup window ?

Or I will have to access it via code.

I want to verify the url of the popup to check if its correct or not in the Then clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once there is a popup, the driver will not automatically focus on the popup. You need to handle it via code.

Here is how I would handle popups.

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
String subWindowHandler = null;

Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
                                            // perform operations on popup

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window
```